# How can I read the stderr of a GUI process that is launched by another process on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, stderr

I want to see the text a program prints to stderr.

I can't see it because the program can only be launched by its launcher so nothing is shown when it's run from the command prompt; the program runs and then the command prompt immediately returns for input instead of blocking and displaying the output.

**Can you think of any technique, even an ugly hack, that will let me read what's being printed to stderr?**

I have a few ideas but I don't know how to carry them out easily:

- Read the memory of the process at the right location
- Modify the memory of the process to change the stderr handle to one I can read
- Hook the API calls that write to stderr
- Hook `CreateProcess` of the launcher and change the output handles

Comment: Inject a DLL, call [`SetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: How do you know the program writes to stderr in the first place?  (GUI programs usually don't, and AFAIK aren't even allowed to, properly speaking.)  But assuming it does, I guess you could inject a DLL and do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27651806/886887).  You'll have to make sure your DLL is dynamically linked to the same C runtime library as the application.